# SQL Server Varchar to VarBinary Conversion

Tags: varchar, sql-insert, varbinary

I have to insert the string "johnmelling" value into a table which has the column as
[USERPASS] varbinary NOT NULL.

Please could any one suggest me, what would be the best conversion to insert "johnmelling"?

I tried to to insert as below,

```
Insert into table(column1)
Values(CONVERT(varbinary(1), 'johnmelling'))
```

Then I got the error

Line 1: String or binary data would be truncated.

Thank You,

Answer (score 4):

You are converting to varbinary(1) so your target datatype is varbinary but the integer you have specified in parentheses is 1 which means your datatype will only have a length of 1; you are receiving that error because the length you have allocated to that datatype is too small. The literal, 'johnmelling' is 11 characters but you are trying to store it in a datatype that has a length of 1.

Simply change the integer in parentheses to 11, 50, 255, max or whatever you think is an appropriate length and you won't get that error.